# Partial Derivatives - Implicit Differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How to think and approach this question?

Find $z_x$ and $z_y$

(a) $z = f(x) + g(y)$

Ans:$z_x =$ $f'(x)$  and $z_y =$  $g'(y)$

I get a and understand it.

(b) $z= f(x+y)$

Not sure how to think about b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you taking partial derivative with respect to $x$, treat $y$ as a constant.

Now apply chain rule,

Hence $$z_x = f'(x+y) \frac{\partial (x+y)}{\partial x}=f'(x+y)$$

I will leave $z_y$ as an exercise.